# Is there anyway to plot timeline charts in excel sheets using Spreadhseet::WriteExcel module in Perl?

Tags: perl

Any kind of links details would be helpful. I went through the  Spreadhseet::WriteExcel module in CPAN but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` provides [Spreadhseet::WriteExcel::Chart](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Chart) to insert charts into Excel documents.

Comment: But there are no timeline charts in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Chart module@simbabaque

Comment: Then there probably is no other way to do that.